# How to pass a Lambda expression as a method argument in JDK8 with reflection

Tags: java, reflection, lambda

In JDK 8, I can use reflection to call a method with a FunctionalInterface parameter, passing a Lambda expression. For instance, this works.

```
import java.util.function.IntPredicate;  
import java.lang.reflect.Method;

public class LambdaReflect {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        System.out.println(test(x->true));
        // Now do this in reflection
        Class<LambdaReflect> thisC = LambdaReflect.class;
        Method meths[] = thisC.getDeclaredMethods();
        Method m = meths[1];  // test method
        try {
            IntPredicate lamb = x->true;
            boolean result = (Boolean) m.invoke(null, lamb);
            System.out.println(result);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static boolean test(IntPredicate func) {
        return func.test(1);
    }
}
```

However, if the parameter type is only known at runtime, how can I pass a lambda expression to the method? In other words, if I don't know at compile time the argument type of the method, but only know that it is a functional interface, can I use reflection to call it with a lambda expression?

Comment: Can you clarify _if the parameter type is only known at runtime_?

Comment: I'm not really sure what you're trying to ask. Please clarify what you are trying to do and why you are having trouble with it.

Comment: `Method m = meths[1];  // test method` doesn't represent `test(IntPredicate func)` method. You would need to use something like `Method m = thisC.getDeclaredMethod("test", IntPredicate.class);`. You can make this code more dynamic but to help you more we need to know precisely what you want to achieve and what data you will have at runtime.

Comment: BTW never ignore exceptions, always handle them, even by simply printing their stacktrace.

Comment: @Pshemo but some exceptions are impossible - they may be declared on a super type for an implementation that will never throw it, eg IOException on methods of ByteArrayInputStream

Comment: @Bohemian Then you assume a property that might later be refactored. Always code against the signature and implicit contract, not against an implementation detail.

Comment: @Bohemian True, `ByteArrayInputStream` will not throw `IOExceptuon` for `read` but lets say that we are using `InputStream` as reference (lets say that it is type of argument in our method) because we want to `read` from multiple streams, or simply because we want to make our code more flexible. In that case even if we know that streams we will use today will not throw any exceptions, but we can't be sure about streams which will appear in the future. That is why I think it is better to have at least `printStackTrace` invoked, so we would know that our code is not perfect yet.

Comment: If you are trying to dynamically adapt methods using reflection a [Proxy](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Proxy.html) sounds like a better fit.

Comment: @McDowell Thanks. I'll look into Proxy. I'll also look into MethodHandler etc, as suggested by Holger below.

Answer (score 5):

You can’t create a lambda expression without knowing the target type at compile-time. But you can put the lambda’s code into a method and create a method reference to this method. This is similar to how lambda expressions are compiled. The difference is that the functional interface implementation is created explicitly using reflective code:

```
import java.lang.invoke.*;
import java.util.function.IntPredicate;  
import java.lang.reflect.Method;

public class LambdaReflect {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        try {
            for(Method m: LambdaReflect.class.getDeclaredMethods()) {
                if(!m.getName().equals("test")) continue;
                // we don’t know the interface at compile-time:
                Class<?> funcInterface=m.getParameterTypes()[0];
                // but we have to know the signature to provide implementation code:
                MethodType type=MethodType.methodType(boolean.class, int.class);
                MethodHandles.Lookup l=MethodHandles.lookup();
                MethodHandle target=l.findStatic(LambdaReflect.class, "lambda", type);
                Object lambda=LambdaMetafactory.metafactory(l, "test",
                    MethodType.methodType(funcInterface), type, target, type)
                .getTarget().invoke();
                boolean result = (Boolean) m.invoke(null, lambda);
                System.out.println(result);
                break;
            }
        } catch (Throwable ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private static boolean lambda(int x) { return true; }

    public static boolean test(IntPredicate func) {
        return func.test(1);
    }
}
```

---

If you want to implement arbitrary functional signatures (which implies that the implementation is rather trivial, not depending on the unknown parameters), you can use [`MethodHandleProxies`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/invoke/MethodHandleProxies.html#asInterfaceInstance-java.lang.Class-java.lang.invoke.MethodHandle-). The difference is that the `MethodHandle` doesn’t need to be *direct* then, i.e. doesn’t need to represent a real method. So you can create a [handle invariably returning a constant](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/invoke/MethodHandles.html#constant-java.lang.Class-java.lang.Object-) and use [`dropArguments`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/invoke/MethodHandles.html#dropArguments-java.lang.invoke.MethodHandle-int-java.lang.Class...-) to insert additional formal parameters until you have a handle with the right functional signature which you can pass to [`asInterfaceInstance`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/invoke/MethodHandleProxies.html#asInterfaceInstance-java.lang.Class-java.lang.invoke.MethodHandle-)

Comment: This works, for this example. Thanks. But looks like I have to include lots methods (like lambda(int) above). One for every signatures that I may have at runtime, multiplied by the number of lambdas that I may pass to the methods. Still, this approach looks promising, and I'll explore it more.

Answer (score 2):

You can always indicate a lambda expression by using a type casting which allows the compiler to infer the functional interface:

```
m.invoke(null, (IntPredicate) (x -> true));
```

However, if you know the signature that well, why would you use reflection? If you want to generate a runtime implementation of an interface, you should implement the interface with a runtime-generated class. Look into Java proxies or my library [Byte Buddy](https://github.com/raphw/byte-buddy.git) for this. This way, you could supply the argument as follows:

```
IntPredicate instance = new ByteBuddy()
  .subclass(IntPredicate.class)
  .method(named("test")).intercept(FixedValue.value(true));
  .make()
  .load(getClass().getClassLoader(), ClassLoadingStrategy.Default.WRAPPER)
  .getLoadedClass()
  .newInstance();
 m.invoke(null, instance);
```

Comment: I use IntPredicate as an an example. In general I don't know what the interface is at compile time, so I cannot use type casting.

Comment: The you might look for runtime code generation. I updated my answer.